Coroutine callback late bound i.e. std::function, indirect co_await
I got a processing class that signals a certain condition via a callback that is bound late at runtime. The processing class is executed by a coroutine, and the signal wants to call a coroutine eventually too.
struct pdu {
    void turn() {
        callback(5);
    }
    /* Not possible due to std::function but preferred
    boost::asio::awaitable<void> turn () {
        co_await callback(5);
    }
     */
    using callback_t = std::function<void(int)>;
    pdu (callback_t callback) : callback(callback) {}
    callback_t callback;
};

boost::asio::awaitable<void> target_co_routine(int x) {
    std::cout << "In target coroutine with parameter " << x << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

/*!
 * @param strand that this coroutine is already running on
 */
boost::asio::awaitable<int> my_coroutine(boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type>& strand,std::shared_ptr<demo::scope_stuff>) {
    std::cout << "In my coroutine" << std::endl;
    pdu my_pdu{[&strand](int x){
        //Not feasible since the strand is already blocked.
        // Can neither release/defer as it would break the order of execution nor use a dispatch semantic
        auto f = boost::asio::co_spawn(strand,target_co_routine(x),boost::asio::use_future);
        f.get();
    }};
    my_pdu.turn();
    co_return 5;
}

So turn() which could be a coroutine, but is not since std::function can not be co_awaited, is called by a coroutine my_coroutine, executed on the strand.
This function calls the callback, which in turn wants to co_await a coroutine target_co_routine eventually, which shall be executed on the same strand, before turn returns.
So is there any type for using callback_t = std::function<void(int)>; or boost::asio functionality, i.e. a different call like the boost::asuo::co_spawn call that lets me achieve this?
I tried to await naive on the std::function but got an error:

error: no matching member function for call to 'await_transform'


"since std::function can not be co_awaited" -- Questionable assertion. On what basis do you make this claim?

On the basis that my compiler errors when I try it, and nobody got a compiling solution where you await it.

Wait a seconds, guess you are right, using callback_t = std::function<boost::asio::awaitable(int)>; seems to work.

"On the basis that my compiler errors when I try it" -- It would have been useful to include that error message in the question for two reasons. First, the error message is an objective observation rather than your (unreliable) conclusion based on the observation. Second, it would have confirmed that you were trying to co_await the wrong signature. (What you wrote is consistent with trying the correct signature and running into some other problem that led you to give up on the correct signature. Doubtful, but possible.)

@JaMiT You are right, I am just a bit ashmed of the wrong assumption and the naive way to try to compile/try just something. But yeah as other likely make the same mistakes as I, I added the compiler error to improve helpfulness, i.e. search visibility.

You can make a coroutine signature by replacing void with awaitable<void>:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using Void     = asio::awaitable<void>;

struct pdu {
    Void turn() { co_await callback_(5); }

    using callback_t = std::function<Void(int)>;
    pdu(callback_t callback) : callback_(std::move(callback)) {}

  private:
    callback_t callback_;
};

Void target_co_routine(int x) {
    std::cout << "In target coroutine with parameter " << x << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

namespace demo {
    struct scope_stuff {};
} // namespace demo

asio::awaitable<int> my_coroutine(asio::any_io_executor strand, std::shared_ptr<demo::scope_stuff>) {
    std::cout << "In my coroutine" << std::endl;

    pdu my_pdu{
        [strand](int x) -> Void { co_await co_spawn(strand, target_co_routine(x), asio::deferred); }};
    co_await my_pdu.turn();
    co_return 5;
}

int main() {
    asio::thread_pool ioc;

    co_spawn(                          //
        ioc,                           //
        my_coroutine(make_strand(ioc), //
                     std::make_shared<demo::scope_stuff>()),
        asio::detached);

    ioc.join();
}

Printing
In my coroutine
In target coroutine with parameter 5

Other Notes
The more general approach is to write async operations e.g. using async_initiate or async_compose which gives the caller the choice of completion token, be it use_awaitable, use_future, detached or anything else.
Also, do not pass executors by reference. Executors are lightweight "references" to execution contexts.

Just read in the comments, that I throw std::function to early out of the window,         pdu my_pdu{[&strand](int x) -> boost::asio::awaitable {
return target_co_routine(x);
}}; works too :-)

Still don't pass the executor by reference, though :)

Noted :-) Thanks

You can just do it. The main problem with your code is that you defined callback_t to hold a regular function, not a coroutine. Make it match the signature of target_co_routine.
using callback_t = std::function<boost::asio::awaitable<void>(int)>;

Then switch to the "preferred" definition of turn() and address the remaining syntax errors. (The lambda has the wrong signature now, but it's no longer needed. The return value of my_pdu.turn() cannot be ignored, so add co_await. The first parameter to my_coroutine is unused, so drop it.) I also dropped the second parameter to my_coroutine because it is unused and also because demo is not declared (much less demo::scope_stuff). Your real code might need that parameter, but in this example, it's just noise.
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct pdu {
    boost::asio::awaitable<void> turn () {
        co_await callback(5);
    }
    using callback_t = std::function<boost::asio::awaitable<void>(int)>;
    pdu (callback_t callback) : callback(callback) {}
    callback_t callback;
};

boost::asio::awaitable<void> target_co_routine(int x) {
    std::cout << "In target coroutine with parameter " << x << std::endl;
    co_return;
}

boost::asio::awaitable<int> my_coroutine() {
    std::cout << "In my coroutine" << std::endl;
    pdu my_pdu{target_co_routine};
    co_await my_pdu.turn();
    co_return 5;
}

This compiles, although I did not actually run this code, primarily because there is a limit to how much time I'm willing to invest in filling in missing pieces from the question. The question does not provide a way to execute this code, so I did not execute it. Still, I have reasonable confidence that it will perform as expected.

Yeah its so simple, but you know how it is, when one starts with a wrong assumption :-)
